# choropleth map time-series map allowing zoom

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, qgis, temporal

I have been using both R and QGIS to study GIS, with the intention of publishing choropleth maps to the web. Both pieces of software allow a zoom function on static maps. But, for animated time-series, the only option appears to be to join a series of time snapshots into a movie file.

I would like the user to be able to zoom in during a time series animation.

I'm animating onto a map of New Zealand, and my time-series is events by suburb. While I can aggregate suburb into territorial local authority area to have larger polygons, this removes the suburb detail. Suburb is likely to remain of interest to users.

Will I have to create a series of animations, one for each general geographical area that people might be interested in (e.g. Auckland, Wellington, Christchurch)? That will provide a "selected zoom" option for users. It also means I have to create a set of static maps per predicted geographical location of user interest.

I can't find any solutions for combining zoom and time series with choropleth maps, at least with R and QGIS.

Does anyone have an example of  this type of web implementation, preferably showing the options used (QGIS) or the code (R)?